# Convert a String with items to a List<String>

Tags: java, converters, arrays

I have a String looking like this: `["a","b","c","d"]`. Notice that this is a `String` and not a String array. However I want to convert this to a `List<String>`. How can I achieve this the easiest way?

Comment: it would really nice if you would share the solution that you are working on.

Comment: @moviaa if it's a String than perhaps is: "[a,b,c,d]" ?

Comment: try to do a split and some string manipulation

Comment: What do you want in your List?  What is the actual String you are parsing? `["a","b", "c", "d"]` is four Strings, in what looks like a JSON array format.  Please be more specific with your exact input and desired output.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper: I'm trying to do a split, but not sure how the regexp should look like. I have tried a few, but can't get it to work.

Comment: @azurefrog: At the bottom it is actually a JSON array. However, I'm working with an Android application where I'm sending a GCM message with this JSON object. In the applications's IntentService I have this message (JSON) in a Bundle. When I try to retrieve this JSON object as bundle.getStringArray(key) I can't retrieve anything. However bundle.getString(key) works and I get the above shown String object.

Comment: @azurefrog it seems pretty clear to me. What OP gave was a single string, starting with a `[`, then a `"`, and so on. He wants the strings that are encapsulated within that string to be placed into a list.

Comment: @moviaa If it's actually legal JSON, why not just use a JSON parser?

Comment: @chiastic-security It's not obvious to me, which is why I asked. There's a rather large difference in my mind between `list.add("a");` and `list.add("\"a\"");` for instance.  Without clarification from the OP, I cannot guess exactly what the input is or how it ought to be parsed.

Comment: @azurefrog: You're right - I was getting too blinded in solving it by parsing myself. I'm now retrieving the JSON as a String object from the Bundle and then parsing it to a JSON-object and then it's quite easy to get a List from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this way?

```
String s = "[\"a\",\"b\", \"c\", \"d\"]";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).replaceAll("[\" ]", "").split(","));
```

**EDIT**

```
String s = "[\"a\",\"b\", \"c\", \"d\"]";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(","));
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    String ss = list.get(i).trim();
    list.set(i, ss.substring(1, ss.length() - 1));
}
```

**EDIT #2**

```
String s = "[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\"]";
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.substring(2, s.length() - 2).split("\",[ ]*\""));
```

Comment: This will go wrong if there are commas in any of the strings.

Comment: In fact it'll also go wrong if there are spaces in the strings!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, this string is just a JSON array - you should just use a JSON parser rather than try to invent your own.

[This other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998203/836214) (and all the other answers on the page) provide some instructions on how to do this.

Answer (score -2):

This is my implementation:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(theString.split(""));
```

Hope that helps. SALAM

**Edit**

Sorry I didn't get the question very well
This is a new implementation:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(theString.replace("\"", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", "").split(","));
list.forEach(e-> e.trim());
```

this not the best implementation but this is what i came with :P